# apollo-server-testing: how to type createTestClient() return? (eslint unbound-method error)

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint, apollo-server, apollo-server-testing

I am trying to setup testing for a `node.js / typescript / apollo-server / typegrapql / typeorm` project using `jest`, `ts-jest` and `apollo-server-testing`. My test server and client are setup like this:

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import connectToDatabase from '../database/createConnection';
import buildApolloSchema from './buildApolloSchema';
import { createTestClient } from 'apollo-server-testing';


let server: ApolloServer;
let query: any; // <- Type here??
let mutate: any; // <- Type here??

export { server, query, mutate };

const setupTestEnvironment = async () => {

  await connectToDatabase();
  const schema = await buildApolloSchema();

  if (schema) {
    const server = new ApolloServer({
      schema,
      context: ({ req, res }) => ({
        req,
        res,
      }),
    });

    const testClient = createTestClient(server);
    query = testClient.query; // <- Error here: Avoid referencing unbound methods...
    mutate = testClient.mutate; // <- Error here: Avoid referencing unbound methods...
  }
};
```

Any idea of how can I type variables `query` and `mutate` to avoid `implicit any` errors? There seems to be some type inference but I don't seem to be able to import types from the `apollo-server-testing` package and so far I have left them as `any` (quickfix suggests `never`).

Right now the assignments at the end are also throwing the error `Avoid referencing unbound methods which may cause unintentional scoping of this.`

[image]

I have tried all sorts of destructuring assignments (including `const {query, mutate} = createTestClient(server)` as it appears in the docs) and I get the same error.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to type `query` and `mutate` with the types from `apollo-server-testing` like this:

```js
import {
  ApolloServerTestClient,
  createTestClient,
} from "apollo-server-testing";

let server: ApolloServer;
let query: ApolloServerTestClient["query"];
let mutate: ApolloServerTestClient["mutate"];
```

The `Avoid referencing unbound methods which may cause unintentional scoping of this.` error is related to the way the types of `createTestClient` are defined. Since that's `apollo-server-testing` code, that's hard for you to resolve. Consider disabling the rule for these lines:

```js
    const testClient = createTestClient(server);
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/unbound-method
    query = testClient.query;
    // eslint-disable-next-line  @typescript-eslint/unbound-method
    mutate = testClient.mutate;
```

The root of the issue seems to be this definition in `apollo-server-testing`:

```js
export interface ApolloServerTestClient {
    query<TData = any, TVariables = Record<string, any>>(query: Query<TVariables>): Promise<GraphQLResponse<TData>>;
    mutate<TData = any, TVariables = Record<string, any>>(mutation: Mutation<TVariables>): Promise<GraphQLResponse<TData>>;
}
```

If the definition would be like this, the rule shouldn't trigger:

```js
export interface ApolloServerTestClient {
  query: <TData = any, TVariables = Record<string, any>>(query: Query<TVariables>) => Promise<GraphQLResponse<TData>>;
  mutate: <TData = any, TVariables = Record<string, any>>(mutation: Mutation<TVariables>) => Promise<GraphQLResponse<TData>>;
}
```

*Edit*: Related to [issue 4724 in apollo-server-testing](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/4724)